# Add more Google Apps to gmail side panel

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-account, google-groups

I mean to add more Google Apps to show when I click on the Waffle icon in the right side panel of Gmail.
In particular, I want to add Groups.
I know I can do two other things:

1. The "+" button only allows for adding Add-ons, not other Google apps.
2. Reordering what is already there by click-and-drag.

but none of this is what I am looking for.

**Is this possible? How?**

Comment: This question was bumped by Community User. What do you think of my answer? Did it help you?

Comment: @Rubén - I usually provide feedback for answers. If I didn't post, it is likely that I didn't have the chance of testing at that time.
I would do so as soon as I have a time to try it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have customized my Google app launcher in several accounts. I have Groups on the app launcher of several accounts, but it's not included in a consumer account created a few months ago. I can't add Groups to the app launcher for this account.

Related thread from the Google Workspace Admin Help community: [Google Groups is not in my apps menu and I can't figure out how to add it back in.](https://support.google.com/a/thread/174325025?hl=en)

---

On the [Google Accounts help center](https://support.google.com/accounts), they included how to customize "the waffle" in the article [Use the Google bar](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1714464?hl=en).

From the [Use the Google bar](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1714464?hl=en):

Note: By menu and launcher, the following text refers to "the waffle".

> ### Customize your menu
>
> You can customize the launcher to show your favorite apps at the top. To do this, drag and drop them within the menu.
>
> Note: To customize your menu, make sure you're signed in to your Google Account.
>
> #### Add more apps
>
> If you'd like to add one you don't see in the list:
>
> 1. Sign in to your Google Account.
> 2. Select Google apps [image: Apps].
> 3. At the bottom of the menu, select More.
> 4. Drag the Google apps you want to the top of the launcher.

The above doesn't include the whole section content; follow the above link to read the subsection: Add apps that aren't in the "More" menu

---

What you are calling "the waffle", Google called "the app launcher" in 2015, ref. [An additional row of apps and customization coming to the App Launcher](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2015/06/an-additional-row-of-apps-and.html).

Comment: I have tinkered a bit with the maze of links, and I couldn't get this to work. Did you actually try this? Could you post more detailed instructions?
The closest I got is in https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1714464?hl=en#zippy=%2Cswitch-between-apps%2Ccustomize-your-menu, under "Add apps that aren't in the "More" menu".

Comment: But for me, step 4 there makes no sense, since: 
1. The app name I want to add to the menu would not show up, that is why I want to add it. 
2.  For the apps that do show up there is no "Add a shortcut" to click; it would make no sense for the same reason, they are already there, so there is no need to Add a shortcut.
**Could you please clarify the process?**

Comment: PS: In https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1714464?hl=en#zippy=%2Cswitch-between-apps%2Ccustomize-your-menu I don't see "More" at the bottom, but "More from google", which upon clicking leads me to page https://about.google/products/#all-products with a list of Google apps. But I found no way to click on an app in that page and drag to the Google apps menu. It is simply a regular web page.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio Yes, I tried this. The design of the app launcher changed a bit since the answer was posted. Maybe the people in charge thought that the article didn't need to be updated.  I suggest you create a new question, adding the specific details of the apps that you want to add. Please bear in mind that the answer might be "Not possible". A workaround might be creating an app that redirects to the app you want to add. The details about how to that be too much work to be posted as a Web Applications SE answer.

Comment: Remember that some Google account / app features are managed by Google Workspace admins. If you are using a Google Workspace account you might have to check first with your admin that this is possible for your account.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio I updated my answer.

Comment: The new links you provided are useful, and they seem to indicate that, at present time, what I mean to accomplish is not possible. Would you agree? If so, perhaps it would be more clear if you state that explicitly in the answer. Extracting the main conclusions from the links provided would also be very helpful.
Plus, I don't understand what do you mean by "adding the specific details of the apps that you want to add." I specify that "I want to add Groups".